# I can't list my boss of 5+ years as a reference

Tags: job-search, references, reputation

About a year ago, I left my job of 5+ years after being passed over for promotions/salary increases for about 3 of those years. I worked for a small organization where people rarely quit other than to retire. It made my boss look very bad, as she had insisted I could be replaced quickly, my contributions to the department did not merit a promotion, and the current salary was fair market value for the work I was doing. While trying to replace me, she told people that no one was applying because I was sabotaging their search by spreading lies about her and the organization because I was bitter. I never did any such thing and I know that any rational human being would know I am not powerful enough to keep strangers from applying for a job nationwide.

Since leaving, I worked for 4 months in my new position, then they had a huge round of layoffs and now I am on the job hunt myself.

My concern is that when I am asked for references, I only worked for 4 months at that startup. Many hiring managers and recruiters will want to speak with the person who managed me for the majority of my career, rather than the most recent manager. I do not doubt that my old boss would take that opportunity to get me back for making her look bad.

So, what do I do when asked for references?  And, what if a recruiter asks me why I don't list my old boss?

Comment: If you work in the US references have become nearly meaningless. So I would not worry overly much.

Comment: Did you gloat in your old boss' face that she failed? How did you know about their hiring process for the new guy, when he quit, and what she was saying about you? Who are these "people" she told? Sounds like you got some insiders at your old company... use them as reference.

Comment: @LokiAstari how so?

Comment: Most companies only allow HR to give references (managers are told to pass such queries to HR) and they will only confirm you worked there and potentially the dates you worked there. They do not allow employes to say anything negative as this opens them up to law suits and there is no reason to say anything positive (unless the person is a personal friend) which makes a positive review practically meaningless.

Answer (score 16):

Find a co-worker or another manager (or several)  who was impressed with you, and cite them instead. The reference doesn't *have* to be your first-line manager.

. If the interviewers ask (which they may not), give the briefest and least emotional version possible of what you told us: "X couldn't find a replacement for me at that salary, and from what I've heard seems to still be grumpy about having let me go. Under the circumstances I'm not comfortable asking X to act as a reference. But I've got these other folks who can say what kind of employee I was there."

Answer (score 9):

> So, what do I do when asked for references?

Find someone else at your old company who would be willing and able to be an effective reference. A different manager that knew you well, a more senior co-worker who knew and respected your work, etc - any of those could be a decent stand-in for a reluctant former manager.

Try to ensure that the person you choose understands your situation with your former manager, and would be willing to explain things appropriately to someone calling for a reference.

> And, what if a recruiter asks me why I don't list my old boss?

Be honest. Something like "Sadly, my manager took my resignation rather hard and unfortunately, we are no longer on good terms." should suffice.

Comment: Better wording than mine.